# Many to Many Table with multiple same-column references

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm designing a document translation DB and struggling to connect the non-generic many-to-many table.

Each document has a title and summary.

Translated Document table:

```
CREATE table translated_documents (
  document_id         bigint references documents (id),
  source_language_id  int not null,
  source_title_hash   uuid, -- md5 hash cast to uuid
  source_summary_hash uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (document_id)
);


CREATE TABLE translations (
  content_hash            uuid not null, -- holds either source_title_hash or source_summary_hash
  translation_language_id int  not null,
  content_translation     text not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (content_hash, translation_language_id)
);
```

An attempt at a many-to-many table, trying to reference the `content_hash` column twice.

```
CREATE TABLE translated_documents_translations (
  document_id         bigint references translated_documents (document_id),
  source_title_hash   uuid not null references translations (content_hash),
  source_summary_hash uuid not null references translations (content_hash),
  PRIMARY KEY (source_title_hash),
  CONSTRAINT same_hash_not_allowed CHECK (source_title_hash <> source_summary_hash)
);
```

My thinking is that documents can be translated into many languages, and translations can work for many documents with the same title or summary. Is there a better way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think unless you have to save space or share a lot of translations you could just do one-to-many mapping `documents` -> `document_translations`

```
CREATE TABLE document_translations
(
    document_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    language_id INT NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    summary TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT document_translations_pk PRIMARY KEY (language_id, document_id)
);
```

Then you could use external [translation memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory) to help with translations.

If you want to share translations then I don't think you need `translated_documents_translations` as many-to-many table. Just use `translated_documents` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE translated_documents
(
  document_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT translated_documents_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY
    CONSTRAINT translated_documents_documents_id_fk
    REFERENCES documents,
  language_id INTEGER,
  title UUID,
  summary UUID,
  CONSTRAINT translated_documents_title_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (title, language_id) REFERENCES translations,
  CONSTRAINT translated_documents_summary_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (summary, language_id) REFERENCES translations
);

CREATE TABLE translations
(
  content_hash UUID NOT NULL,
  language_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  translation TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT translations_content_hash_language_id_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (content_hash, language_id)
);
```

And `JOIN` `documents` -> `documents_translations` -> `translations`

Comment: I also get `ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "translations"`.

Comment: Isn't working because the foreign key `content_hash` must be unique, but that defeats the whole purpose as there need to be multiple content_hash / language_id pairs for for the multiple languages.

Comment: To address the one-to-many suggestion: I need to minimize the number of translations performed, not necessarily space, which is the reason for the hashing. Thank you so much for the translation memory tip, though it is a bit much for my current task.

Comment: You could compose the hash from `content` and `language_id` to produce unique hash - but that feels a little bit hacky

Comment: @AustinCawley-Edwards answer updated. It turns out you can reference compound primary key. I hope it makes sense...

Comment: I've decided to go about it a different way but I'll accept your answer because it was helpful getting there and I think others might benefit from your research!